# sort algorithm implemented in Python has problem

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I want to sort Strings in ascending order.

For example, s = 'Zbcdefg' returns answer 'gfedcbZ'

```
def solution(s):
    answer = ''

    while True:
        max = s[0]

        for j in range(1,len(s)):
            if ord(max) < ord(s[j]):
                max = s[j]

        answer += max
        s= s.replace(max,'')

        if len(s) == 1:
            answer += s[0]
            break


    return answer
```

This is my code but some test cases are not solved with this. I don't know why. Can you find any logical error in this code?

Comment: Is this a project or do you only want to sort a string?

Comment: That indentation looks messed up.

Comment: @AnnZen this is just for study! I know its better to use sort() but I just want to know what is the problem in this code.

Comment: @pjs if you are saying about else part, it is not an mistake because I use it as a end of the for loop

Comment: @DongGyuLee shouldn't that construction only be used as an alternative to ending the loop with `break`?

Comment: `s= s.replace(max,'')` replaces across the entire string, not just the first substring, so repeated characters will cause unexpected results. There are other issues; it'd help if you offered an explanation for your approach. Have you tried to debug this? Which test cases fail?

Comment: @MarkMeyer The OP's example shows reverse only.

Comment: @pjs Oh I didn't know that and I edited my code but still the other test cases are not solved with this..

Comment: @ggorlen I got it!!! That was the problem. I solved it as `s.replace(max,'',1)` Thank you!!!

Comment: Good job! Feel free to post a [self-answer and accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Also, please don't name a variable `max` because that overwrites a builtin function.

Comment: @ggorlen Alright! I didn't know about self-answering my question so thank you for letting me know how to do it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of this code was in `s = s.replace(max,'')`. If a character searched as a highest order is stored as `max` (even though the name is not that proper bcz it can overwrite built in func) and pop it out from the original string `s` using `s.replace(max,'')`, the problem is that method can delete the unexpected character(s) which is the same as `max` but not the `max` that I found.

Therefore, I fixed it as `s.replace(max,'',1)` to replace only one character firstly matched in string `s`.